# Why my pagination datatable doesn't work when use Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I want to disable some button with condition.. 
Im already disable that button but my pagination doesn't work. Both function is work but when im using both function in the same time, it is doesn't work. Can you help me?

This is my HTML/JSP

```
<div id="dt_example" class="example_alt_pagination">
    <table class="table
    id="data-table" >
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th class="text-center">Un-Used</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <s:iterator value="checkList" status="status">
        <tr >
            <td class="text-center"  id="unUsedWarkat<s:property value="%{#status.index}"/>"><s:property value="unUsedWarkat" /></td>
            <td class="text-center" id="totalWarkat<s:property value="%{#status.index}"/>"><s:property value="totalWarkat" /></td>
            <td class="text-center"><s:property value="statusWarkat" /></td>

            <td class="text-center">
                <s:url id="delete" action="warkat_book_maintenance_delete" escapeAmp="false">
                <s:param name="idwebTknUrl" value="idwebTknUrl" />
            </s:url>
            <a href="<s:property value="delete"/>"> 
            <button onClick="disableDelete()" class ="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="delete<s:property value="%{#status.index}"/>">
            Delete
        </button>
    </a>
</td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Ths is my Javascript/jQuery

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var i;
    var unUsed;
    var totalWarkat;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length;i++) {    
        unUsed = document.getElementById('unUsedWarkat'+i).innerHTML;
        totalWarkat = document.getElementById('totalWarkat'+i).innerHTML;
        if(unUsed != totalWarkat){
            document.getElementById("delete"+i).disabled = true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("delete"+i).disabled = false;
        }

    }  

    $(document).ready(function() {

        myFunction();

        var table = $('#data-table').DataTable({
            "iDisplayLength": 5,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sDom": '<"pull-left top"t><"col-sm-4">tr<"clear"><"bottom"ilp>',
            "bSort" : false,
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks.. and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Try removing  button through jquery
https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons().remove()